# Unable to see the results section when creating a table in SQL

Tags: sql, visual-studio-code

I'm new to programming and just learning the basics of C# and SQL in Visual Studio Code, so this might be a piece of cake for the pros here :)
I was trying to create and edit a table, but I'm unable to see the results section, I only see the messages part. Tried the suggested ctrl+alt+r but nothing pops up. Just wondering then if it's similar to Visual Studio that has the option to 'Show Table Data' and edit the table.

The results section appears as follows:

[image: screenshot]

and the screenshot from VS (just for reference):

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

You can use this [mssql extension](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/visual-studio-code/sql-server-develop-use-vscode?view=sql-server-ver15) by Microsoft.

Expand the database and right click to the table and choose "Select TOP 1000". Then you should be able to see the results like the image below.

[query results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AZiaG.jpg)

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I have already installed the mmsql extension, but still unable to see any results ;(

Comment: Can you add more information about what you've tried so far? The difference I see looking at the image is that the window is docked below the editor, in my case it appears on the right. Did you try to colapse the message section to see if the results window was hidden?